# delete belongs_to instance if no instances of has_many exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

For these models:

```
class Folder < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :documents_folders_requests, dependent::destroy 
end

class DocumentsFoldersRequest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :folder
  belongs_to :child_folder, class_name: "Folder", optional: true
end
```

If a `DocumentsFoldersRequest` record is deleted, and no other `documents_folders_request` record exists which uses that `Folder` record for either the `folder_id` or the `child_folder_id`, is there a way to automatically delete the `Folder` record? It would be considered "orphaned" at this point - since it is not found on any association, and there's no `folders_controller#index` to display all the folder records anywhere.
Can this be done from the model?

example:

```
dfr = DocumentsFoldersRequest.find_by(document_id: 123)

folder_id = dfr.folder.id 
=> [1]

dfr.destroy_all
=> true

# is there a better way to write the following: 
if DocumentsFoldersRequest.where(folder: folder_id).nil? && DocumentsFoldersRequest.where(child_folder: folder_id).nil?
  folder = Folder.find(folder_id)
  folder.destroy
end
```

Comment: are you looking for [active record transaction-callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#transaction-callbacks)? like you can put your `folder.destroy` code inside of `after_commit` of model `DocumentsFoldersRequest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options. Mostly it comes down to when you want to do this.

I'd suggest you do it when deleting a `DocumentsFoldersRequest`

Any time you delete one, check the parent `folder` and `child_folder`:

```
class DocumentsFoldersRequest < ApplicationRecord
  after_destroy :check_for_orphaned_folder

  def check_for_orphaned_folder
    folder.destroy if folder.documents_folders_requests.none?
    child_folder.destroy if child_folder.documents_folders_requests.none?
  end

end
```